# I want to get all links from dynamic webtable column and click on each of them in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a dynamic webtable where it has ID column. I want to get all links from this ID column and click on it one by one. Should I use list to save all the values and using for loop iterate through it? I am new to webdriver so not sure about it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can simply use list and store all the links.

I have a list of many hyperlinks by below text :View / Select Monitors. So I stored all the links simply in a list.

And then I can click on any link by passing the value I want.

If you want to click on all the links then you can simply use a for loop and click it.
For example:

`List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.linkText("View / Select Monitors"));`

```
     //Click on first hyperlink with matched text
```

## list.get(0).click();

2nd Example:

`Step1.[Getting all the links by tagname]`

`List<WebElement> allLinks = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));`

`Step2. [Storing the total size for the number of links]`

`int s =allLinks.size();`

Step 3.[I am printing all the links here and there position]

for(int i=0;iString txtlink=allLinks.get(i).getText();
            `System.out.println("%n"+i);//Getting the value of i and hyperlink`
             `System.out.println(txtlink);`
              `allLinks.get(i).click`;//You can simply pass the value of i and 
                                      click on it
             `Thread.sleep(2000)'
         }

```
In this way you can get the value of "i" also and then click if you like if you need to click on any particular link and if you want to click on all then simply use .click inside the loop.`enter code here`
```

I hope it helps.